# Powershell remove items from specific folder in path (for all users)

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-2.0

So I have this script. I enter a users username and it goes and looks in the given location using that username to remove all files fine the end directory.

I now need to schedule this for all users now I have proved it works. How can i get this to go through all user folders in given location and then through the path to the end directory to remove the files. Not sure how I can modify this to remove the need for the users username.

Any ideas?

```
"`n" 
$user = Read-Host "Enter Username"
write-Host "Finding" -ForegroundColor Green
$filePath = "\\myserver\d$\userprofiles\$user\AppData\Roaming\app\app2\app3\$user" 
"`n" 

$Response = Read-Host "Do you want to delete the contents of the app directory for '$user' ?(Y/N)"
if($Response -eq "Y"){
   get-childitem  $filepath -recurse | foreach ($_) {remove-item -verbose $_.fullname} 
} else{
Write-Host "No such user found or directory does not exist..."
}

write-Host "" 
write-Host "------------Process Complete Files Removed--------------------" -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should sniff users' names from `\\myserver\d$\users` you can do this by calling `Get-Content` on the folder, then looping `foreach-object` through output and skip `Default`as that is a system folder and not really a profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem "\\myserver\d$\userprofiles" -Exclude "Default" | ForEach-Object {
    $path = $_.FullName + "\AppData\Roaming\app\app2\app3\" + $_.Name + "\*"
    Remove-Item $path -Recurse
    }
```

Comment: after remote-item $path would I then add the -recurse? I am doing -whatif on the script to test it out before I run just want to make sure I can see what will happen and being prompted about the recurse

Thanks again so far it looks good.

Comment: Because $path is a folder, yes. Sorry about that.

Comment: Ok works well, but it removes the final directory as well as the files in it, I just need to remove the files the final directory must stay. Other than that it looks spot on.

Comment: Ok, added a little bit more to the end of the path. Should be good now.

Comment: Legend. Marked as answered. I am going to send an email at the end of this planned task to say it was completed. Is there any way I can pull in a list of file paths (not files) that the action happened against so I can show in the email what was done effectivley. I need to get on a PS course. Enjoy using it but still need to get my head round it all. Thanks for the help Tim. Great.

Comment: You could store all our some of that $path variable in an array of append it to a string so you can access all the values once the delete action is finished.